# Mongo query in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin

When I query

```
db.inventory.aggregate({"$group": {"_id": null, "avg": {"$avg": "$size.h"}}})
```

mongo returns me

```
{ "_id" : null, "avg" : 12.77 }
```

as expected.

However, when I implement this query in Spring with

```
@Query("{\"\$group\": {\"_id\": null, \"avg\": {\"\$avg\": \"\$size.h\"}}}")
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $group' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $group' on server localhost:27017",
    "path": "/avg",
    "status": 500,
    "timestamp": "2018-11-15T00:44:14.011+0000"
}
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: What happens when you remove the escape characters? `@Query("{"$group": {"_id": null, "avg": {"$avg": "$size.h"}}}")`

Comment: [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is an **aggregation pipeline stage operator** and **cannot** be used with `@Query`. And before you ask, "stages" cannot be used even with [`$expr`.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am still unsure how to solve my problem. How would you go about implementing the query then?